# Creating separate models in single form with accepts_nested_attributes_for (b/t & has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, mass-assignment

Trying to use nested attributes to create an `Organization` and a `User` in one form.  I'm getting the following error: *Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user (ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)*

Pulling my hair out on this one

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name, :users_attributes
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy      
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users  
end
```

**user.rb** (using devise)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email     
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

**new.html.haml**

```
= form_for @organization do |f|

  = f.label :name, "Company Name"
  = f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Company Name"

  = f.fields_for :user do |ff| -# tried :users here and the form doesn't render
    = ff.label :email, "Email Address"
    = ff.email_field :email, placeholder: "Email Address"

= f.submit "Create Account"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered a lot on Stackoverflow.

```
f.fields_for :users
```

And in the controller, you need to build a user:

```
@organization.users.build
```

You get `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user` because the user attribute is not accessible, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!  i was going off of a railscasts where he hadn't used `build` anywhere in the controller. i was under the impression that `accepts_nested_attributes` took care of the building for you, but i guess it makes sense to build explicitly in the controller